# what's a good alternative to Java7 WatchService?

Tags: java-6, watchservice

i need to pick a frameWork similar to watch service available on Java7 .
what's a good alternative framework t to track changes on file System .

thanks in advance

Comment: How's this related to JavaScript?

Comment: just to say that i'm open to javascript alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

You can use JNotify event library . It allow java application to listen to file system events, such as create ,modify , rename ,delete.

[jnotify Link](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

if you use nodeJS. 
[Chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) is very interesting . A neat wrapper around node.js fs.watch / fs.watchFile.

```
var chokidar = require('chokidar');

var watcher = chokidar.watch('file or dir', {ignored: /[\/\\]\./, persistent: true});

watcher
  .on('add', function(path) {console.log('File', path, 'has been added');})
  .on('addDir', function(path) {console.log('Directory', path, 'has been added');})
  .on('change', function(path) {console.log('File', path, 'has been changed');})
  .on('unlink', function(path) {console.log('File', path, 'has been removed');})
  .on('unlinkDir', function(path) {console.log('Directory', path, 'has been removed');})
  .on('error', function(error) {console.error('Error happened', error);})

// 'add', 'addDir' and 'change' events also receive stat() results as second argument.
// http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats
watcher.on('change', function(path, stats) {
  console.log('File', path, 'changed size to', stats.size);
});

watcher.add('new-file');
watcher.add(['new-file-2', 'new-file-3']);

// Only needed if watching is persistent.
watcher.close();

// One-liner
require('chokidar').watch('.', {ignored: /[\/\\]\./}).on('all', function(event, path) {
  console.log(event, path);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use [commonIO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/monitor/package-summary.html)

start to look at :
http://andreinc.net/2012/06/30/writing-a-simple-file-monitor-in-java-using-commons-io/